# What is the posterior distribution of $\delta_1$ given $y_1$ and $y_i = \delta_i + w_i$

Tags: time-series, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose $y_i = \delta_i + w_i$,

where $\delta_1 \sim N(30, 5)$ and $w_i \sim^{iid} N(0, 0.5)$.
Assume that $\delta_1$ is independent of $w_i \forall \ i$.

a) Given $y_1 = 30$, what is the posterior distribution of $\delta_1$ given $y_1$? That is, what is $n_1$ and $m_1$ in $\delta_1 \sim N(n_1, m_1)$?

b) Suppose $\delta_i = \delta_{i-1} + v_i$ for $i \geq 2$, where $v_i \sim^{iid} N(0, 
0.5)$ (*$w_i$ and $v_i$ are mutually independent). What is the predictive distribution of $\delta_2$ given $y_1$ (recall $y_1 = 30$)? That is, what is $n_2$ and $m_2$ in $\delta_2 \sim N(n_2, m_2)$?

My approach:

I think we need to find the mean using the expected value, so $E[\delta_1|y_1] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\delta_1*Pr(\delta_1|y_1)$. But I don't know any probability about $y_1$..

Comment: Search our site for "conditional normal:" you will find a great many formulas.

Comment: @whuber i think i got it! thank you